# Process TOP(n) records with an SQL CTE in an SQL WHILE Loop

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, common-table-expression

First timer here, so if I am doing something wrong, please do not hesitate in telling me.

I have a situation where I know what to do, but I do not know how to do it. Situation is as follows:

Take records from one table - now each record has to be split into two parts into a new table. This means I take 1 record and it ends up being 2 in another table. For this purpose I have made a CTE with SQL. This works perfectly. It splits the record into two parts. This is what the CTE looks like :

```
WITH 
cteFirstLine (Field1, Field2, Field3) AS
    (
        SELECT TOP 1000 T.Field1, T.Field2, T.Field3
        FROM Table1 T
        LEFT JOIN Table2 P ON T.Field1 = P.Field4   
        ORDER BY Field2 DESC    
    )
, 
cteSecondLine(Field1, Field2, Field3) AS
    (
        SELECT TOP 1000 T.Field1, T.Field2, T.Field3
        FROM Table1 T 
        LEFT JOIN Table2 P ON T.Field1 = P.Field4   
        ORDER BY Field2 DESC    
    )
,
 cteUnified  (Field1, Field2, Field3)
  AS
  (
       SELECT Field1, Field2, Field3
       FROM cteFirstLine

       UNION

       SELECT Field1, Field2, Field3
       FROM cteSecondLine
  )

INSERT INTO Table_TEST(Field1, Field2, Field3) 

SELECT TOP 2000 Field1, Field2, Field3
FROM cteUnified
```

OK, so this works. The problem I now have is that The old table, the table from which I have to process these records contains almost a million records. I know it is a lot, but it used to be way more than that, hence this task.

I need to know: how can I use this CTE inside a loop? Will a loop suffice? How would I consturct the loop so that it can do everything automatically. By Automatically I mean instead of doing only 1000 records at a time, but more.

Can anyone please help?

Comment: why `TOP 2000`? if both parts of the union are top 1000, the maximum number of rows can't be more then 2000 anyway...

Comment: Is there a reason that you're limiting to 1000 (or 2000) at all? Have you tested it by just doing the `INSERT` for all of the rows? A million rows isn't actually a lot by most RDBMS standards and should process in seconds at most.

Comment: Also, unless `Field2` is a unique column (either a PK or a single column in a unique index) this code might not work as you expect/want it to. The 1000 rows from each CTE might not be the same rows. One last question... what's the reason for the join to `Table2`? I assume that there's more to this query than you're showing?

Comment: Tag dbms used. (Some non-ANSI SQL there.)

Comment: @Tom H. The reaosn for the 1000 records is mainly for testing purposes, but we will be implementing a similar solution step by step as the data is quite sensitive and we just want to ensure nothing gets lost of messed up. This is the full query. The join is necessary to get the correct data linked to it